# how do we do convert speech to text based on indian accent using google could APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am trying to convert speech to text by using `google could APIs` like this `gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running` when I use `--language-code='en-US` this code I am able to convert perfect and that text is coming based on audio of `US` accent or `UK`.

When I am trying to conevrt Indian accent that text is coming totally wrong and I have tried `en-in`  but no use.

how  am I  converting ? : Here I am uploading (.wav) audio file and converting as text.

How can convert  this indian accent through `google could API` what are the changes I have to do.

Can any one help on it?.

Thanks

Sandeep.

Comment: Does the api support changing accent?

Comment: Yes [link]https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/speech/recognize-long-running[/link]  ```--language-code=LANGUAGE_CODE```

Comment: Yes https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/speech/recognize-long-running ,     ```gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running AUDIO --language-code=LANGUAGE_CODE [--async] [--encoding=ENCODING; default="encoding-unspecified"] [--filter-profanity] [--hints=[HINTS,…]] [--include-word-time-offsets] [--max-alternatives=MAX_ALTERNATIVES; default=1] [--sample-rate=SAMPLE_RATE] [--audio-channel-count=AUDIO_CHANNEL_COUNT --separate-channel-recognition] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]```

Answer (score 0):

The accent and pronunciation can vary from person to person. I tried with  a sample example where I gave the speech as **“Speech-to-Text enables easy integration of Google speech recognition technologies into developer applications. You can send audio data to the Speech-to-Text API, which then returns a text transcription of that audio file”**.

The output text is accurate to the input speech.

```
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.8974054,
          "transcript": "speech to text enables easy integration of Google Speech Recognition Technologies into developer applications you can send audio data to the speech to text api which then returns a text transcription of that audio file"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There are some factors that can affect the accuracy of speech:

1. Capture audio with a sampling rate of 16,000 Hz or higher. Values lower than this may impair speech recognition accuracy, and higher levels have no appreciable effect on speech recognition quality.
2. The [hints arguments](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/speech/recognize-long-running#--hints) in the gcloud command can be used to improve the accuracy for specific words and phrases.
3. When using the REST API for speech to text transcription results can be improved with [speech adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation#improve_recognition_of_specified_words).

For hints argument in gcloud the command looks like this : **gcloud ml speech recognize-long-running gs://your_bucket/audiofile --language-code=en-IN --hints=[transcription,api,data]**

For using speech adaptation using REST API you can refer to this sample:

```
{
 "config": {
   "languageCode":"en-IN",
   "speechContexts": {
     "phrases":[“Recognition”, "speech to text"]
    }
 },
 "audio":{
   "uri":"gs://bucket/audiofile"
 }
}
```

Use the curl command:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize \
    -d @speech1.json
```

If this does not work for you, please provide the audio file that you are using.